# How can I run an SQL script from a file using camel-SQL

Tags: apache-camel

I'm playing with the camel-SQL component in order to run a quartz-scheduled SQL report. My SQL is a lengthy query and I prefer to format it such that it spans many lines (92 lines to be exact) even though it *could* be formatted into a single reaaaallly long line of text.

My preference is to place this script into an external file and then run it. Alternatively, I could put it into a properties file (not really my preference), but I tried that and even after adding a backslash '\' at the end of each line, it still causes an exception for some reason. Ignoring that issue for the time being, how might I run this script using camel SQL with the script residing in an external file? Seems like it ought to be easy, but I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [jdbc component](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) that accesses databases through JDBC, where SQL queries and operations are sent in the message body.

Example:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("jdbc:myDataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true")
    .log("result = ${body}");
```

Tested with:

```
final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", "select p.ID, p.PROJECT from projects p");
```

Instead of a passing a static string to the body you may read your SQL statement from a file:

```
final String sql = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/sql/select.sql"));
template.sendBody("direct:start", sql);
```